# IE11 Copy/Paste Not Able to Retrieve Local Path from Clipboard Javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, copy-paste

I have a customer who insists on using IE11 and wants copy/paste capabilities from File Explorer, into our web app which is an Angular front-end application.

We have provided them with drag/drop, select files, and even managed to get copy/paste from Snipping Tool to work as well...all within IE11.

However, their users want to... go into File Explorer, click on a file, press CTRL+C and then go back into IE11, click on the upload area and press CTRL+V.

I thought clipboard or datatransfer would at least hold a path reference somewhere but I've looked through the event objects and can't seem to find them.

Does anyone know if you can get the local file path of the copied file from File Explorer?  That would at least get me 80% of the way there. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want the file path? That would get you nowhere. You wouldn't be able to do anything from this path anyway. But normally (though I never tried on IE11), you should be able to get the File directly, which I guess is more useful than the path, isn't it?

Comment: @kalido - it absolutely would be better if it would actually work on IE11. It works like a charm on everything but IE11. I was hoping it would be a base64 or blob or something, but nothing. I know something is definitely different since when I copy a file from file explorer and then try to paste in the div, no paste event on my listener fires. So unless it’s under a different event I don’t think it’s possible.